# Dropdown Menu Basics

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this relative simple dropdown menu and dont get it.
Why is it only showing the last menu everything is beneath the last one?
And when i click on it, it first shows the name followed immediately by another alert saying "undefined". 
Here is the dropdown, on hover the submenu shows.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.dropbtn {background-color: #4CAF50; color: white; cursor: pointer;}
.dropdown { position: relative; display: inline-block;}
.dropdown-content { display: none; position: absolute;}
.dropdown-content a { display: block;}
.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content { display: block;}
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn { background-color: #3e8e41;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="dropdown">
 <input type="button" id="dropbtnID" value="Select" class="dropbtn">
  <div class="dropdown-content">    
    <input type="text" value="a" id="a" class="dropdown-content">
    <input type="text" value="b" id="a" class="dropdown-content">
    <p id="c" name="c" class="dropdown-content">cc</p>
    <p id="d" name="d" class="dropdown-content">dd</p> 
</div></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".dropdown-content").click(function(){
      var name = $(this).attr("name");
      alert(name);       
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry to say that it is just everything wrong...CSS and HTML are not correct, classes badly used (and so relative css)

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap here? Your code does not have any actual HTML dropdowns.

Comment: Check this for a very easy idea about dropdown https://jsfiddle.net/7e82q0br/

Comment: NICE work @Yuri - just one thing - same issue with the id for "b" is currently "a"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are many issues with the code. first you have the same id ("a") for both a and b :

```
<input type="text" value="b" id="b" class="dropdown-content">
```

and the reason you are geting the undefined alert is that you have the parent div with the same class as the elements within the dropdown - so therefore the first alert is for the element (such as `name="d"`) and the second one is for the parent div with no name (hence `"undefined"`).

Then there are the layout issues. All in all - you need to go back through the code and fix each line up.